# error al subir archivos con librería requests de python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Estoy subiendo archivos a google cloud storage con el [rest api](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics?authuser=1)

realizando un curl como tienen en el ejemplo funciona todo bien

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @[OBJECT] \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -H "Content-Type: [OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE]" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o?uploadType=media&name=[OBJECT_NAME]"
```

pero al realizar un post con requests de python el archivo se sube dañado

```
import requests
filepath = '/home/user/gcs/image.jpg'
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/****/o?uploadType=media&name=image.jpg'
authorization = 'Bearer ******'

headers = {
    "Authorization": authorization,
    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
}

with open(filepath, "rb") as image_file:
    files = {'media.jpeg': image_file}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
    print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo parecido, tambien te adjunte la doc.

```
import requests

# En esta parte es recomendable usar os.path https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html
file = {'media': open('/home/user/gcs/image.jpg', 'rb')}

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/****/o?uploadType=media&name=image.jpg'
authorization = 'Bearer ******'

headers = {
    'Authorization': authorization,
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=file)
print(r.content)
```

Doc: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: y que diferencia hay con el código de la pregunta? y como se supone que soluciona el problema?